# When does C (using minigw) decides to stop accessing value of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void ar1(int *a);
int main()
{
   
int a[][3]={{100,200,300},{500,900,800},{9,88,45}};
ar1(a[0]);
    
}
void ar1(int *a)
{
    while(1)
    {++*a;
    printf("%10d",*a);
    ++a;
    printf(" || %10d \n",a);
    }
}
```

and output is

```
        101 ||    6422272 
        201 ||    6422276 
        301 ||    6422280 
        501 ||    6422284 
        901 ||    6422288 
        801 ||    6422292 
         10 ||    6422296 
         89 ||    6422300 
         46 ||    6422304 
    4194433 ||    6422308 
    6422289 ||    6422312 
    6422357 ||    6422316 
    4199049 ||    6422320 
          2 ||    6422324 
   12591553 ||    6422328
   12588985 ||    6422332
         -2 ||    6422336
          3 ||    6422340
          1 ||    6422344
    6422357 ||    6422348
 2001176782 ||    6422352
    4034561 ||    6422356
    6422405 ||    6422360
    4199158 ||    6422364
          2 ||    6422368
          1 ||    6422372
          1 ||    6422376
          1 ||    6422380
          1 ||    6422384
          1 ||    6422388
          1 ||    6422392
 2004908970 ||    6422396
    4034561 ||    6422400
 2004908945 ||    6422404
    6422493 ||    6422408
 2007416108 ||    6422412
    4034561 ||    6422416
  991310042 ||    6422420
          1 ||    6422424
          1 ||    6422428
    4034561 ||    6422432
          1 ||    6422436
          1 ||    6422440
          1 ||    6422444
          1 ||    6422448
          1 ||    6422452
          1 ||    6422456
          1 ||    6422460
          1 ||    6422464
          1 ||    6422468
    6422417 ||    6422472
          1 ||    6422476
    6422501 ||    6422480 
 2007494273 ||    6422484
 1288080694 ||    6422488
          1 ||    6422492
    6422509 ||    6422496
 2007415984 ||    6422500
          0 ||    6422504
 2007601904 ||    6422508
          1 ||    6422512
          1 ||    6422516
    4199137 ||    6422520
    4034561 ||    6422524
          1 ||    6422528
```

why does it stop there?
What these value signify?

Well I tried accessing 2d array using pointer. Then I tried to access the memory which i shouldn't till the end of memory. It stops at sometime. I wanna know why?

to me it seems like it reached the end of memory allocated to compiler. and these are not gibberish rather self-referencing pointers? i

Comment: I mean, in this case, there is no limiting factor, memory reads are exceeding the length of the array. Running this on cpp.sh website, it goes on for a lot longer. If you are experiencing a segmentation fault, it means you have reached an area that you are no longer permitted to read within the bounds of your thread or application. Otherwise, I have no idea how or why the code would stop before then without OS intervention.

Comment: C simply have no bounds-checking. It's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure your program doesn't go out of bounds of array or allocate memory.

Comment: Also note that the proper format specifier to print a `void *` pointer (cast *is* needed) is `%p`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. Which also going out of bound does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude isn't that a security issue?

Comment: @TyQ. yup seems like device based issue

Comment: Yes, plenty of issues in public programs have had these problems, and buffer overflows and out of bounds accesses are by far the most common problem. But it's not part of C, never has been and never will be. It's very much a hands-off language, that lets you shoot yourself in you feet whenever you want.

Comment: Yes it is a security issue, and that too is the programmers responsibility.  C is a _systems level language_, it does nothing hidden, and can do anything, just exactly what the code says. It requires minimal run-time support (no interpreter, no VM, no OS even).  Such languages need to exist (otherwise all systems level work would have to be written in assembler). Any handling of erroneous behaviour is system dependent. For example if you exceed the bounds of some MMU protected region and cause a processor exception, it is the system that handles the exception.

Comment: .... Static analysts tools can be applied to detect security flaws in C code.  Runtime analysis tools such as Valgrind or BoundsChecker can also be used during testing.

Comment: Addresses in decimal make things less than clear.  The final address in hex is 0x620000. Plausibly an MMU page boundary.  You should in any event use %p format specifier for pointer presentation.  Use `-Wformat -Werror` to allow the compiler to trap such errors.

Comment: Was some error message printed when the program stopped? Did you view the output in a terminal window or was it captured in a file?

Comment: @EricPostpischil On windows, programs sometimes crash without leaving any error message.

Comment: You got a number of answers.  Remember to accept the best one by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

0. Your program is poorly formatted.  Readability matters.
1. `ar1()`: The pointer `a` may only be formed till 1 past the end of the underlying array.  As is your program is undefined behavior.
2. `ar1()`: The pointer may only be dereferences (`*a`) for the 3 elements of the underlaying array.  This is another undefined behavior and it usually results in a segmentation fault when the program tries to read memory it does not have access to.  This is probably why your program stops where it does.
3. `ar()`: The format specifier `%d` is used to print an `int`, but you pass it a pointer.  This is another undefined behavior.  Instead you want to use `%p` and cast the pointer to `(void *)`.  The first `int` value is what is stored in your array in `main()` but incremented by 1, and the 2nd value is address of the next element.

Here is a well behaved version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ar1(int *a, size_t n) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ++*a;
        printf("%10d",*a);
        ++a;
        printf(" || %p \n", (void *) a);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a[][3]={{100,200,300},{500,900,800},{9,88,45}};
    ar1(a[0], sizeof a[0] / sizeof *a[0]);

}
```

and the output (addresses will change from run to run even on my machine):

```
       101 || 0x7ffc17037444 
       201 || 0x7ffc17037448 
       301 || 0x7ffc1703744c
```

Comment: all this is correct but I don't think that's  what OP is looking for. OP seems well aware that the program is illegal. OP is rather what it is that makes the program run for a while and then stop.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Is my answer "This is another undefined behavior and it usually results in a segmentation fault when the program tries to read memory it does not have access to. This is probably why your program stops where it does." not clear?

Comment: For some reason I missed that line.

Answer (score 0):

> "When does C (using minigw) decides to stop accessing value of pointer?"

The compiler you use has nothing to do with when C will stop reading the value of a pointer. So using MinGW doesn't matter.

(In Layman's terms) C compiles to machine code and that machine code is managed by the OS and executed by the CPU. C code is no longer dependent on the compiler after compilation.

With that being said, different parts of the application will be put in different segments of memory at runtime. For example, the stack may be allocated in some random spot in memory with the heap memory being at some different location. It is randomized for security purposes. You can read up on ASLR which is Linux's way of implementing this from this [Medium](https://medium.com/@boutnaru/security-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization-part-1-overview-3aec7fec01e0) article.

In your case, the way ASLR or Windows' equivalent might affect you is that your stack code could be placed closer or further from the application's memory boundaries. Meaning it would vary as far as how long it may run each time.

C has no limiting factor outside of what it is programmed to do. In your code, you are not setting any boundaries for the loop to end. As such, the loop will run contiguously, at least until the OS decides to stop it.

The majority of the values you are getting are uninitialized. Meaning that they are garbage values, either randomly generated or remnants from previously stored data. So they do not signify anything. When C initializes a variable, it sets its value to something expected. Normally, an empty initialization would set the value to 0. An uninitialized instantiation of a variable would produce a garbage value and may cause some warnings to appear from the compiler.

In most cases, you will get a segmentation fault when you try to access memory outside of your application's allocated memory space. That basically means that the OS gave your application some memory and your application tried to read or write outside of that allocated memory. This can be particularly dangerous because it would mean that your application would overwrite memory used by other applications or by the OS itself, which can pose major security risks and data-loss and system instability.

Keep in mind that running this code would also overwrite proceeding instruction memory as well, not just data, as realistically they are one and the same.

I personally couldn't tell you why your program would exit without a segmentation fault / system interrupt if that is what indeed happened. It would have to be killed by the OS or CPU in some way because otherwise it would continue forever.

To resolve this issue, you would simply specify a limiting factor for your loop, such as making it a for loop with an incremental condition i++ < # of elements or simply check for a custom set final value as you would with a null terminator in a string.

Just to clarify, this code is analogous to a buffer overflow.

Comment: Re “your stack code could be placed closer or further from the application's memory boundaries”: In modern general-purpose multi-user systems, there is plenty of virtual address space, so guard pages are placed around the stack. These guard pages are deliberately marked non-accessible so they will catch errors in going beyond the stack bounds. This will cause the distance from a fixed object on the stack, like OP’s array, to the address that triggers an exception, just above the stack, to be constant.

Comment: Re “… your application would overwrite memory used by other applications…”: The segment fault is not what prevents an application from overwriting memory used by other applications, because the memory of other applications is not mapped into the process’ address space at all. There is no address in the process’ virtual address space that corresponds to the memory of another application, except when they have deliberately arranged to share memory.

Comment: Re “Keep in mind that running this code would also overwrite proceeding instruction memory as well, not just data, as realistically they are one and the same”: It cannot because there are guard pages between the stack and the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that as far as the C language os concerned, nothing at all can be said about it. There are no rules that it must obey. It may run for a while and then stop. It may not run at all. It may run forever, printing random verses from Poe's "The Raven".  It may set your computer on fire and eat your lunch. Anything is allowed.

In practical terms however we can invoke our knowledge of the specific platform your program runs on, and also of the ways C compilers generally work. Using that knowledge we can *guess* that the program, after overrunning the array boundary, *probably* continues to access memory that happens to be physically adjacent to that array, as if it is a part of that array. This happens until the program runs out of the memory space that was allocated to it by the OS. This is a fatal error and the program is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The program loader sets up memory for your program. This includes mapping the instructions of your program into virtual memory, allocating some memory for general data of your program, and allocating some memory for the program stack. In modern computer systems with plenty of virtual address space, the stack is preceded and followed by *guard* pages, which are addresses in virtual memory that are deliberately not mapped to physically memory and are marked not to be used. The reason for this will become evident below.

When the program loader finishes its initial setup of memory for your program, it transfers control to a special start routine in your program. (This routine is automatically linked into your program by the linker even though it is not listed among the files you tell the linker to include in your program.) This program performs some initialization, including setting up some data on the stack, and then calls the `main` routine in your program. The `main` routine sets up its stack frame. This includes placing the data of your `a` array on the stack. (It likely gets this data by copying it from the general data area mentioned above, which was filled from data in the executable file of your program, and the data in that file contains the initial values for your array because the compiler and the linker placed them there.)

So, the memory for your array `a` is on the stack. That means the pointer you pass to `ar1` points to a place on the stack. When you increment this pointer and use it to print the contents of memory, you see what data is on the stack (except modified by your increment of one). You see the contents of your array, then other values that `main` has in its stack frame, then values that the start routine has in its stack frame. These values include addresses of other things that `main` needs, such as the address of the stack frame of the start routine and the return address of the start routine. Knowing specifically what all of these values are would require having information about the code in `main` and in the start routine.

Also note that your program prints `a` after `++a`, so the address it prints on each line is the address **after** the value shown on that line, not the address of the value on that line. When your program reaches address 6422528, that is the top of the program stack. In hexadecimal, this is 620000<sub>16</sub>. Those zero low bits show us that address is the boundary of a memory page. When your program tries to access that address, it is attempting to access a location in the guard page.

The guard page is deliberately marked not to be used so that programs that contain bugs that cause them to go a little beyond the stack boundaries will crash. When the program attempts to access this memory marked not to be used, the computer processor processes an exception, which suspends execution of your program and informs the operating system your program had a problem. The operating system then terminates your program.